# How to pass variable into field id javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to this stuff - I've got some code that's working, but not very elegant:

```
function cost(){
var runningcost=0
  if (document.getElementById('field_280_0').checked==true)
    {
    runningcost=100;
    }
  else 
    {
      if (document.getElementById('field_281_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }
      if (document.getElementById('field_282_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_283_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_284_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_285_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_286_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_287_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_288_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_289_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }if (document.getElementById('field_290_0').checked==true)
      {
      runningcost=runningcost+12
      }
    }if (document.getElementById('field_292_0').checked==true)
    {
    runningcost=runningcost+55
    }
document.getElementById('[[Total cost#id]]').value=runningcost;
}
```

I am trying to use a for loop to get rid of all the if lines:

```
for (var i=281;i<292;i++)
    {
        var field = i.toString();
                if (document.getElementById('field_'+ field +'_0').checked==true)
            {
            runningcost=runningcost+12
            }
    }
```

I've tried lots of variations on that theme but I'm always getting stuck with getElementById as null.

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Your loop seems fine at a glance. What's the HTML look like? Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: what browser u r using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem was with

for (var i=281;i<292;i++)

It works now as

for (var i=280;i<291;i++)

I think that I was forgetting that the i was being added to before each pass (not sure of the technical way to call it here), so it needed to start 1 below the field number needed, if that makes sense.

It seems to work with or without `var field = i.toString();` - I got rid of it to keep the code clean, if it's not needed.

Thanks all for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the var field = i.toString();

I tried a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Diesel9Design/ME6FE/) to see if it works that way, and it does.

Html:

```
<div id="field_285_0"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
for (var i=281;i<292;i++)
{
    if(document.getElementById('field_'+ i +'_0')) {
        $('body').append('exsists: '+ i );   //<-- Just added this to check my if statement
    };
}
```

Comment: actually using var field = i.toString() runs on Safari fine .. what Explorer @Chris is using ?